# Crash on lollipop devices only, Failed resolution of: VrVideoView$Options

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using [this](http://trimensions.org/node/83) to use 360 video in my app. The problem is I am getting `classDefNotFound` error when opening the video and only on lollipop devices.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView$Options; 


 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView$Options
```

I don't understand why its working fine on `Marshmallow` and `Nougat` devices, and crashing just only on `lollipop` devices.

This is my Gradle tree, Kindly guide me what can be the reason of crashing. I am not using proguard, I have also enabled `Multidex` but nothing is really helping here.

```
debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :common
+--- project :commonwidget
+--- project :videowidget
+--- com.farApp:farApp-android-sdk:2.1.3
|    +--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0 -> 1.6.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0 -> 2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.6
|    +--- com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.3
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0 -> 25.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5
|    +--- org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.2
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:design:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads: -> 9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1 (*)
+--- :hologram-1.0.2:
+--- :SDK-APP-TEST-2.1.8:
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.2
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.12
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10 (*)
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.0
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
|    |    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    \--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:2.1.0
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    \--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:2.1.0
|         +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.twitter:twitter-text:1.13.0
|         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|         \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5
\--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1

+--- project :extVP
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.6.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0 -> 2.4.0 (*)
+--- org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.0.1
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.0.1 (*)
|              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.0.1 (*)
+--- io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+ -> 2.6.1
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.6
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 25.0.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1 (*)
+--- io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0
+--- it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:9.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0 (*)
+--- com.twotoasters.servos:util:1.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.twotoasters.servos:util-otto:1.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.6
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0
+--- com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.1
|    \--- com.commonsware.cwac:sacklist:1.0.+ -> 1.0.3
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3
+--- me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+ -> 0.2.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.1
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5
\--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1
```

**Gradle Tree after adding com.google.vr:sdk library**

```
+--- com.google.vr:sdk-audio:1.10.0
|    \--- com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.10.0
|         \--- com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.10.0
|              \--- com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.1.0
\--- com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.10.0 (*)
```

**common module: build.gradle**

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('common.aar'))
```

**common widget: build.gradle**

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('commonwidget.aar'))
```

**video widget: build.gradle**

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('videowidget.aar'))
```

Comment: Are you using release build? Please post proguard-rules.pro file

Comment: I am not using `proguard`, I am working on a debug build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compile these dependencies [as mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started#start_your_own_project):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.40.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-commonwidget:1.40.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget:1.40.0'
}
```

Remove `compile project(':common')` and similar dependencies.

Also pay attention to prerequisites:

- Android Studio, 2.2.2 or higher.
- Version 25 of the Android SDK.
- Gradle 23.0.1 or higher. Android Studio will allow you to upgrade if your installed version is too low.
- A physical Android device running Android 4.4 (KitKat) or higher for Cardboard apps or a Daydream Ready phone.

Comment: Thanks, After adding these, Its giving me following error message.
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processUniversalDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.vr.cardboard'`

Comment: I have added the updated Gradle tree in the question

Comment: It seems to me you haven't uploaded all the dependencies tree, because searching `com.google.vr.cardboard` return nothing. Basically, this means, that one of your libraries that you have imported already contains package `com.google.vr.cardboard`. Remove that from your modules or even remove those module dependency if it only contains cardboard dependency.

Comment: This is complete tree, There is only 1 `cardboard` library that i can see in the current Gradle tree, and if i remove these dependency, there is no `cardboard` libraries i can see in the tree. 
This is how i am generating `gradlew.bat app:dependencies`

Comment: Check your `common`, `commonwidget` and `videowidget` for presense of `com.google.vr.cardboard` package. Gradle tree won't display them as dependencies as long as they are included in the module.

Comment: I have updated my question, These module just contains an `aar` , a `build.gradle` and an `iml` file. I have added their gradle file in the question

Comment: Can i exclude libraries from a module? 
`compile project(':common'){
exclude group: '' , module:''
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) This worked like a charm. Now 1 other library is crashing on lollipop , i will try my best to find a way to fix it. 1 Final question, does changing position of dependencies make any impact?

Comment: I believe it doesn't.